# Visual Studio 2015 - Clang version not found when building from command line

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, clang

I have a Xamarin-based solution in Visual Studio 2015. One of the projects is an Android native shared library containing C++ code.

When I build the solution from within VS 2015 IDE, everything works as expected. However, when I try to build the solution from the command line I get an error.

The build command is:

```
 msbuild mytest.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=ARM /t:Rebuild
```

The error I get is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(64,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for Clang_3_8 (Platform Toolset = 'Clang_3_8') cannot be found. To build using the Clang_3_8 build tools, please install Clang_3_8 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".`

My Visual Studio 2015 has all the updates applied. Wondering if anyone knows what the problem could be. Is it a path problem? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it is a path problem. Make sure to use the developer command prompt link under Program Files-->Visual Studio 2015->Visual Studio Tools. This batch file sets up proper paths, including the one for clang.